# how to import nested module from nested module

Tags: python, python-2.7

Simple question, but could not find the answer.
I've following structure:

```
./lib1:
main.py

./lib2:
__init__.py  utils.py
```

From the root diretory, I'm running:

```
python lib1/main.py
```

and in main.py I want to import lib2/utils.py.

adding import lib2/utils.py fails.
One solution I found is to add:

```
~/tmp/root$ cat lib1/main.py

import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import lib2.utils

lib2.utils.foo()
```

which is good, but I wander if there is other solution. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to be able to import things from `lib2` the directory containing `lib2` should be added to your `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Are `lib1` and `lib2` separate modules? If yes, the comment by @BrenBarn applies: You need to add the top directory (containing `lib1` and `lib2` to the Python path (e.g using `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or appending to `sys.path`).

If both `lib1` and `lib2` are part of one module (i.e. there is a `__init__.py` file in the top directory) you can use relative imports (https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by using the wrong directory structure. The `main.py` script should be in the same top-level directory as the package that it needs to import. So the structure should look like this:

```
project /
    lib2 /
        __init__.py
        utils.py
        other.py
    main.py
```

The directory of the `main` script will always be added to the start of `sys.path`, so this will guarantee that any packages in that directory can be always be directly imported, no matter where the script is executed from.

To import the `utils` module into `main.py` (or `other.py`), you should do:

```
from lib2 import utils
```